# File Server on High Availability (HA) Setup for LAMP?

Tags: nfs, cluster, file-server, high-availability

I'm not sure what is the most proper way (industrial standard) to setup the High Availability servers (especially for LAMP Stack).

Lets say i have:

- 2 Load-balanced Web Servers (Apaches)

Question:

- Best way for the File Server for this Apache pool?

I'm talking about the H.A Setup of the "code files". *(Because "Database" can be another story, on DB Servers. And the "Media Contents" can be on Amazon S3 nowadays)*

So for this, the only way i know (using) until now is:

- Bring up 1 NFS Server
- Share the Drive out
- Mount it on 2 Apache Servers

But i know this way **(NFS) is not very reliable**.

So again, what is the most proper way (industrial standard) to setup the High Availability servers (especially for LAMP Stack) please?

Comment: You could use a distributed filesystem like GlusterFS (or perhaps Ceph if you've got a larger deployment). I'm using GlusterFS for this exact purpose -- keeping the webroots of two servers synchronized -- and while it isn't the fastest and the SSL setup was a pain in the neck due to lacking documentation, it certainly does its job.

Comment: dear @n.st, could you then please share some good resource to start with pls? (i know i can just google, but since you've started it working, may be you could point some quick start guides?) thanks much!

Comment: It's been a while since I set that up, but I'll check if I can still find the information I used when I get to my desktop computer.

Comment: For now, I can only throw you a few links: [GlusterFS' Quick Start Guide](https://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/QuickStart), [advice on what (not) to do with replicated filesystems](https://joejulian.name/blog/glusterfs-replication-dos-and-donts/) (although not all of that might be relevant for your use case), and [one of the few usable articles on how to configure GlusterFS to use SSL when transferring data over the network](http://blog.onefellow.com/post/76702687553/enable-glusterfs-ssl-mode).

Comment: hi, thanks again for your kind help. Actually I've tried it from GlusterFS site yesterday, and it's working already! Your suggestion to use GlusterFS was essential. :)

Comment: So please post your answer by mentioning GlusterFS there. So that I can mark yours as the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a version control system to store web served data in. That gets you:

- The ability to easily roll back if you made a mistake;
- The ability to store the data on the local filesystem of each server, rather than having to use a fileserver (you just check out the repository twice, once on each server).

You do need some way to ensure that changes end up on both/all webservers in a timely manner, though. You can use either a "pull" (cron job on each webserver) or "push" (hooks in the version control system which trigger an update) mechanism for that. What's most appropriate depends on many things.

Two popular version control systems are subversion (centralized) and git (decentralized, my favourite).

Comment: Thanks for great approach. Actually I use this way on some projects, and it really works well. And safe. But I just wanna know how to setup a H.A system properly. Thanks again. :)